# issue with mysqli query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Friends i am stuck and need your help!

When using MySql to make dynamic menu i use the query **SELECT * FROM pages WHERE ParentID = 0** and for sub menu **WHERE ParentID = '$PageID'** ... however this approach do not seems to work when using MySqli .. one of the major reason what i see is Query should be written outside of the function because within function it simple do not work .. dont know why. Anyway here is my code and i hope you friends can help me in solving the issue

```
function Get_menu() {
    $menuQuery = $mysql->query("SELECT PageTitle, PageID, ParentID FROM pages WHERE ParentID = 0");
    while (($row = $menuQuery->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
        echo '<li class="menu-item"><a href="page.php?pageID=' . $row["PageID"] . '">' . $row["PageTitle"] . '</a>';
        $PageID = $row["PageID"];
        $SubmenuQuery = $mysql->query("SELECT PageTitle, PageID, ParentID FROM pages WHERE ParentID = '$PageID'");
        if($SubmenuQuery->num_rows > 0) {
            echo '<ul class="sub-menu">';
            while (($rowx = $SubmenuQuery->fetch_assoc()) !== null) {
                echo '<li class="menu-item"><a href="page.php?pageID=' . $rowx["PageID"] . '">' . $rowx["PageTitle"] . '</a></li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
```

I have tried writing query outside of function but then the query for submenu do not work as it assume $PageID as 0. 
Dear friends it would be a big favor if you can help me please
Thank You

Comment: Fixed up code formatting as it was a bit hard to read.

Comment: That code can and SHOULD be rewritten as a single JOINed query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$mysql` is not defined inside your function scope. You should pass it as a parameter:

```
function Get_menu($mysql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to analyse this:

```
$query = 
"SELECT PageTitle, PageID, ParentID 
FROM 
  pages subs 
INNER JOIN 
  pages cats 
ON 
  subs.ParentID = cats.PageId 
GROUP BY PageID" ;
```

Or your database is gonna be pwn3d and stressed if you are going to fetch categories 1 by 1.